# Issue with constrOptim

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

When doing constrained optimization using the `constrOptim` function, I sometimes get the following error message:

```
Error in optim(theta.old, fun, gradient, control = control, method = method,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

**Example**

```
x <- c(-0.2496881061155757641767394261478330008685588836669921875, 
        0.0824038146359631351600683046854101121425628662109375, 
        0.25000000111421105675191256523248739540576934814453125)

nw <- length(x)
ui <- diag(1, nrow = nw)
ui <- rbind(ui, rep(0, nw))
ui[cbind(2:(nw + 1), 1:nw)] <- -1
ci <- rep(-0.8 / (nw + 1), nw + 1)

constrOptim(theta = rep(0, nw), f = function(theta) mean((theta - x)^2),
            grad = function(theta) 2 * (theta - x), ui = ui, ci = ci, 
            method = "BFGS")
```

**What I know**

The problem occurs during the iteration inside `constrOptim`, when the result comes so close to the boundary that almost all point evaluated by the BFGS optimizer are `NaN`s (excluding the initial point). In this case, BFGS will sometimes return an optimal value of NaN and a corresponding minimizing parameter outside the constraint set.

In `constrOptim`, the objective function fed to BFGS is given by

```
R <- function(theta, theta.old, ...) {
  ui.theta <- ui %*% theta
  gi <- ui.theta - ci
  if (any(gi < 0))  {
    return(NaN) 
  }
  gi.old <- ui %*% theta.old - ci
  bar <- sum(gi.old * log(gi) - ui.theta)
  if (!is.finite(bar)) 
    bar <- -Inf
  f(theta, ...) - mu * bar
}
```

**My question**

It seems to me that the obvious solution to the problem is to simply return `sign(mu) * Inf` instead of `NaN` if there are any `gi < 0`, but could this fix lead to other problems?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think you gradient function should also take the `mean`.

Comment: You should probably rethink your problem formulation, if the solution is to diverge to infinity.

Comment: @Roland, it shouldn't be the mean, but I have forgotten to normalize it. It should be 2 / nw * (theta - x). Then this specific example does not give an error any more, but I am quite sure that this does not fix the issue in general.

Comment: If you have a suggested modification and testing on edge cases is favorable, then submitting to R-devel would be that appropriate route. Modifications of the core packages is rarely done these days. So I'll warn you: unless you can demonstrate truly buggy behavior then throwing an error in an optimization procedure is probably not going to convince that very critical audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After normalizing the gradient properly

```
constrOptim(theta = rep(0, nw), f = function(theta) mean((theta - x)^2),
            grad = function(theta) 2 / nw * (theta - x), ui = ui, ci = ci, 
            method = "BFGS")
```

I can no longer replicate the problem. It seems that the issue was caused by the wrong weighting of the gradient of the objective function and the gradient of the logarithmic barrier term in the internal gradient.

However, I still think that returning Inf outside the boundary would be more robust than returning NaN.